# Exporting static lib symbols from DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I'm using a Facade DLL to a static lib. The Dll provides a small interface and resource management to be shared across multiple DLLs. The Dll-Header do expose stuff from the static library:

```
class DLL_EXPORT MyDllClass {
public:
   /// ...
   OneStaticLibClass * ptr;
};
```

The Problem is: if this should works I've to link the **StaticLib** to the DLL and the application using DLL. I didn't manage to export parts of the **StaticLib** correctly. I tried in the export headers:

```
class DLL_EXPORT OneStaticLibClass;
```

but that doesn't work... I still get:

```
undefined reference to OneStaticLibClass::~OneStaticLibClass(void)
undefined reference to OneStaticLibClass::operator<<(char const *)
```

Andy ideas how I can export parts of the static library with the DLL?

Thank you!

Comment: More details please. Show code.

Comment: The problem with a static library is that you don't find out what code you forgot to write until you link it.  So do make sure that you actually wrote the implementation of the destructor, it is very easy to forget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a .def file and pass it to the linker. DLLEXPORT is not necessary in this case.

The reason for this is the way symbols are resolved when using a static library. When you create a DLL, only those symbols needed by the DLL itself are searched, and object files containing these symbols are copied into the DLL. If the DLL code does not reference your destructor, it will not be included.

A .def file will tell the linker which functions are exported. Exported functions will be searched and pulled from the static library.

One downside of this process is that you need to use mangled C++ names in the .def file. Mangled names can be obtained with the dumpbin utility.

Comment: Thank you! Does it have to be done by hand or is it possible to create a .def file with VisualStudio while building the static library?

Comment: I don't know of such a possibility but I'm no big Visual Studio expert. But if you are building the static library yourself, why not include these same source files in the DLL project too? It's much easier this way.