# Force MSVC to export all symbols of a static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a dll project with some C++ code inside and a static library linked to my project with a set of headers.

There's no references to the functions of my static library inside my C++ code but I want MSVC to export all the symbols of the static library and I don't know how to do it.

The static lib is in my VS project but when I compile my project, dumpbin says that only my C++ functions are exported, there's not a single trace of my static lib.

Comment: This is just guesswork, but if it were me I would try adding the symbols I wanted to export to the DLL project's .DEF file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting static lib symbols from DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608695/exporting-static-lib-symbols-from-dll)

Comment: I've tried everything I seen here and it does nothing